# File Poller FileListFilter cast exception

Tags: spring-integration

Doing exploratory work before I drink the kool-aid.

I am trying to create a simple inbound channel adapter to monitor a directory for new ZIP files.

In order to deal with the ever-present "is it complete?" question, I am trying to adapt the example posted [here](http://www.deha-solutions.com/spring-integration-example-file-inbound-channel-adapter/) to incorporate a FileListFilter which checks the modified time of the file.

However, I am getting the following exception:

```
a boolean result is requiredclass java.util.ArrayList is not assignable to class java.lang.Boolean
at org.springframework.util.Assert.isAssignable(Assert.java:368)
at org.springframework.integration.filter.AbstractMessageProcessingSelector.accept(AbstractMessageProcessingSelector.java:61)
at org.springframework.integration.filter.MessageFilter.handleRequestMessage(MessageFilter.java:103)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:134)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
```

I had this working well with a simple router based on the file extension, but when I replaced it with this filter it fell apart. Seems the actual list of files is what the Assert is trying to cast to Boolean.

Is it not possible to have a filter wired between an inbound and an outbound adapter? Or must I do the file move to the destination myself in the filter? (The way it is done in the linked example)

Here is the config:

```
<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="filePoller" directory="file:input" channel="filesChannel" filename-pattern="*.zip">
   <int:poller fixed-rate="2000" max-messages-per-poll="10" />
</int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>
<int:filter input-channel="filesChannel" ref="lastModifiedFileFilter" output-channel="zipFilesOut"/>

<bean id="lastModifiedFileFilter" class="FileFilterOnLastModifiedTime">
    <property name="timeDifference" value="10000"/>     
</bean>
<int-file:outbound-channel-adapter id="zipFilesOut" directory="file:target/output/zip" delete-source-files="true" />
```

Here is the filter:
    import java.io.File;

```
import org.springframework.integration.file.filters.AbstractFileListFilter;

public class FileFilterOnLastModifiedTime extends AbstractFileListFilter<File> {

Long timeDifference = 1000L;

@Override
protected boolean accept(File file) {

    long lastModified = file.lastModified();
    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    return (currentTime - lastModified) > timeDifference ;
}

public void setTimeDifference(Long timeDifference) {
    this.timeDifference = timeDifference;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `FileFilterOnLastModifiedTime` bean should be provided to the inbound adapter using the `filter` attribute.

```
<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="filePoller" directory="file:input" channel="zipFilesOut" filename-pattern="*.zip"
        filter="lastModifiedFileFilter">
   <int:poller fixed-rate="2000" max-messages-per-poll="10" />
</int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

An inline `<filter/>` element is a simple POJO that takes some argument and returns a boolean.

Since you are providing an `AbstractFileListFilter`, the framework is trying to invoke `filterFiles` which takes an array and returns a `List`, not a boolean.